# Passing Command Line Arguments to java From JPackage Script

Tags: shell-script, parameter

I installed [Rachota](http://rachota.sourceforge.net/) -- a time tracking program written in Java -- from the Fedora repo, and yum installed the `rachota.jar` file to `/usr/share/java`, but it also created a script at `/usr/bin/rachota`. That script is used to launch Rachota, instead of calling `java` directly.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to pass command line arguments to the `/usr/bin/rachota` script and get them passed to `java`.

The script is part of the [JPackage](http://jpackage.org/) project and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# rachota script
# JPackage Project <http://www.jpackage.org/>

# Source functions library
_prefer_jre="true"
. /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions

# Source system prefs
if [ -f /etc/java/rachota.conf ] ; then
  . /etc/java/rachota.conf
fi

# Source user prefs
if [ -f $HOME/.rachotarc ] ; then
  . $HOME/.rachotarc
fi

# Configuration
MAIN_CLASS=org.cesilko.rachota.gui.MainWindow
BASE_FLAGS=""
BASE_OPTIONS=""
BASE_JARS="rachota"

# Set parameters
set_jvm
set_classpath $BASE_JARS
set_flags $BASE_FLAGS
set_options $BASE_OPTIONS

# Let's start
run "$@"
```

Obviously it's parsing `/etc/java/rachota.conf` and `$HOME/rachotarc`, but my shell scripting experience is pretty limited, and I can't figure out what to put in the `$HOME/.rachotarc` file to pass the arguments.

This is the java command I want to eventually run:

`java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB -jar /usr/share/java/rachota.jar`

The `jar` parameter is passed automatically, but I want to pass the `Duser.language` and `Duser.country` parameters too.

Comment: This should also be tagged `JPackage`, but I don't have the points yet. Could somebody please do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part is the `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` file. I just found it [online](http://www.jpackage.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/jpackage/src/jpackage-utils/java-utils/java-functions?revision=1.5&view=markup) and it seems to support additional flags. After looking at the file (the run and the set_flags functions are the important ones) it seems  that it should be enough to provide `ADDITIONAL_FLAGS` to the command:

```
ADDITIONAL_FLAGS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB" /usr/bin/rachota
```

If you want to debug it you may want to set `VERBOSE` to print more details about the executed argument:

```
VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/rachota
```

If you want to have these settings persistent you can also set the variables directly in `$HOME/.rachotarc` or `/etc/java/rachota.conf`

Comment: I used `ADDITIONAL_FLAGS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB"` (without the /usr/bin/rachota), but it worked. Thanks :)